# Android: How to suppress warnings by variant?

Tags: java, android

The below method is only accessible from the debug-build.

```
void initDebugSettings()
```

I want to suppress the unused warning by adding.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
void initDebugSettings()
```

But if I stop using this method in debug build, **I do want to see this warning**.
So what I want to do is something like that:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused", "in-release") // suppress the warning in release variant only
void initDebugSettings()
```

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Comment: to do things differently in build variants u must use variant folders that Gradle supports, meaning instead of putting the file in the main folder in the module, you should put in debug or other flavors like flvDevDebug

Comment: Yeah @mohsensameti you are right. So if I got `initDebugSettings` in class `A` in main, and some function that calls it in class `B` in debug, you will get `unused` warning once compiling in release